# Validation of XML Sitemap urlset with xhtml:link inside url element

Tags: xml, xsd, xhtml, xml-namespaces, sitemap

I am trying to create a sitemap such as the below and I get this error:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xhtml:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
     <url>
         <loc>http://www.something.com/something</loc>
         <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="http://www.something.com/something" />
     </url>
 </urlset>
```

Error:

> http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"> ^ Error 1866: Element '{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}urlset', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}schemaLocation': The attribute '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}schemaLocation' is not allowed. on line: 3
>
> '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}link': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard.

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

There are two issues in this document:

1. The schemaLocation attribute must be in the XML Schema Instance namespace.
2. The url element is invalid, because its definition says `processContents="strict"` and the schema for XHTML was missing so that there was no xhtml:link declaration in scope.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
       http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
       http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
       http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd">
     <url>
       <loc>http://www.something.com/something</loc>
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="http://www.something.com/something" />
     </url>
   </urlset>
   ```

Comment: Unbelievable how many searches I had to do to find this `<urlset>` combo supporting validation and the `<xhtml:link>`. Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450542/namespace-prefix-xhtml-on-link-is-not-defined-sitemap-xml

Comment: I updated all the full qualified links to https and it worked after that.

Comment: Yeah, old thread, but thanks, this solved a puzzle for me too. Though, I trimmed the definition down to <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_schema.html"> which was all I needed to parse the <xhtml:link> tags.

Answer (score 7):

Old one - but still comes up when searching.
Actually the issue is that you are using xhtml:link and then you need "other" urlsets...http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_schema.html http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_schema.html">
```

Reference:
[XML Sitemap rendering as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923627/xml-sitemap-rendering-as-plain-text)