# namespace prefix xhtml on link is not defined - sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, sitemap

I am trying to add language to my sitemap.xml file, but I get a "namespace prefix xhtml on link is not defined" error. How do I defined it? I cannot find anything useful on google.

Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.leepio.dk/</loc>


</urlset>
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this stuff but Google's example here seems to be using a different set of namespace thingies: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en

Comment: You managed to define the `xsi` and the `schemaLocation` prefixes…

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This would do the work.

**Change**

```
<urlset
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
    http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
>
```

**Explanation**

Define the `xmlns:xhtml` as given. Map the `xmlns:xhtml` to a place, where the schema is stored `http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd`.

Comment: it did work, thank you. Looks like WooRank.com has some problems with its detection of site data as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193346/validation-of-xml-sitemap-urlset-with-xhtmllink-inside-url-element